# How to use flask variable in href tag?

Tags: python, flask

Below is the code to upload a file using flask and python and then I wish to use the `filename` variable in href tag!

I am trying with `{{filename}}` but I can't access it.

```
    def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file = request.files['file']
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            path = "./audiofile.txt"
            filepath = open(path, "w")
            filepath.write(filename)           
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
            filepath.close()
            os.system('python ../speech-to-text/slow.py')
            os.system('python ../sentiment-analysis/test.py')
            return redirect(url_for('index'))
    return """
    <!doctype html>
    <head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>Online audio/video transcription!</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/bootstrap.min.css"/>
  </head>
    <title>Upload new File</title><br>
    <center>
    <h1>Upload new File</h1><br>
    <form action="" method=post enctype=multipart/form-data>
      <p><input type=file name=file><br/><br/>
         <input class=btn-success type=submit value=Upload>
    </form>
    <hr>
    <h4>Download transcript file (with sentiment analysis) <a href="tmp/{{filename}}.txt">here</a>!</h4>
    </center>

    <p>%s</p>
    """ % "<br>"
```

Comment: the HTML part above is returned outside of the if statement. The variable 'filename' is created inside of the if statement, at the end of which there is a redirection to url_for('index') (I don't know how a template for index looks like), so it won't even reach the HTML code you pasted here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is kind of vague, but I'll try to answer what I'm guessing you are asking.

In order for you to use filename variable in a HTML using Jinja2 synthax, you would first have to pass that filename into the HTML.

so your simplified view function will be something like below

```
@app.route('/upload_something/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_something():

   # a line to produce filename variable or to get it back from HTML is needed here

   if request.method == 'POST':
       # your upload starts here.


   return render_template('file_upload.html', file_name = file_name)
```

Once you pass the file_name into the HTML, then you can start using utilizing it using Jinja2 synthax {{file_name}}